# Amazon Lightsail for MEAN 2 stack: Bitnami package or OS only + tools?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, bitnami

I'm creating an application in MEAN 2 stack (with Angular 4) and I'm about to upload it to Amazon Lightsail.

I know there is a [MEAN Instance support made by Bitnami](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NO1HJ56), but I couldn't find what vesion of Angular they include in their package and whether I can install the version I need.

Another option seems to be install just the OS and later install the tools that I need by myself. It's doable, since I've done it in my local machine. I'm not a great fan of this solution since I don't know in depth all the tools and I could miss some configuration that could lead to a security issue.

So, what is the better choice here? If someone faced the same problem, what was your solution and why?

Answer (score 0):

In the Bitnami MEAN stack you can install the latest Angularjs version just typing `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Then you just need to build the skeleton using `ng new my-app` in your application directory.